# Can't remove double quotes from image path after JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a JSON file with objects containing the file path to an image.  I'm trying to replace the src attr of an image tag using jQuery but no matter what i do, by the time I try to change the source, the file path has quotes around it which ends up leaving encoding around the path and thus fails.

I've tried:

- decodeURIcomponent
- regex

Neither has worked but I am more than willing to accept that they did not work due my error.

Here's the code as I have it now:

```
getPics : function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : this.BASE_URL +'js/image1.js',
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(data){
            var pic = data.images.image[0].image_one;
            console.log(pic);
            setTimeout(function(){
                var image = JSON.stringify(pic);
                image = image.replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:");
                console.log(image); 
                $('#pic1 img').attr("src", image);
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem portion is this part here:

```
           setTimeout(function(){
                var image = JSON.stringify(pic);
                image = image.replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:");
                console.log(image); 
                $('#pic1 img').attr("src", image);
            }, 5000);
```

Note the two console.logs: the first one for 'pic' prints a clean (i.e.w/out quotes) file path.  Oddly enough, the console.log for 'image' prints out the same file path but now with the evil double quotes which is the final product that fails.  The regex seen appears to have no effect.

Here's the JSON returned that I'm working with:

```
{
"stat": "ok",
"images": {
    "image": [
        {
            "image_one": "images/image_1.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried once without JSON.stringify, i think its not required

Comment: What does `pic` contain? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Thilo: I've edited my question and included the JSON object I'm storing in 'pic'.

Comment: @SatpalSingh: Would you believe you are correct?  I think this *issue* I've posted about is a product of not enough sleep!  Thanks for pointing out the obvious to me! Doh!  If you post as an official answer, you've got my green check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try once without JSON.stringify, i think its not required.